# Matching rownames with a string contained within a column

Tags: r

I have a problem with finding an efficient code that matches rows with columns in a matrix, and generates a new vector with all the matches.

I have a very large matrix. As an example, lets say there is a matrix called "test" like this one:

```
row <- c("aaa" , "bbb" , "ccc")
column <- paste(rep(row, each = 3) , rep(c(1:3) , times = 3) , sep = "_")

test <- matrix(rexp(90), nrow = 3 , ncol = 9)

colnames(test) <- column
rownames(test) <- row
```

In my case, this gives matrix `test`:

```
         aaa_1     aaa_2     aaa_3     bbb_1      bbb_2     bbb_3     ccc_1     ccc_2      ccc_3
aaa 0.08695083 0.5360101 0.2151808 0.2623833 0.05368126 3.5040455 0.3966199 1.1790225 0.16178868
bbb 0.26399994 0.2753358 0.3457663 2.1826606 0.73636302 0.8346718 0.9535214 0.4230223 1.59374844
ccc 0.84269411 0.1526342 0.5687740 0.7493685 0.68945927 2.7006906 0.6448158 1.0599139 0.05998212
```

So I would like to create a new vector called `test1` that matches rows with columns of the same string. In my case I could use:

```
test1 <- c(test[grep("aaa" , rownames(test)) , grep("aaa" , colnames(test))] , 
           test[grep("bbb" , rownames(test)) , grep("bbb" , colnames(test))] ,
           test[grep("ccc" , rownames(test)) , grep("ccc", colnames(test))])

names(test1) <- column
```

and this would give me:

```
     aaa_1      aaa_2      aaa_3      bbb_1      bbb_2      bbb_3      ccc_1      ccc_2 
0.08695083 0.53601009 0.21518077 2.18266063 0.73636302 0.83467182 0.64481582 1.05991387 
     ccc_3 
0.05998212
```

But this code is terrible if I have a gigantic matrix and vector. Would there be a more efficient way of doing this?

Also, in this example there is a string of three characters, but in my matrix there are string with differing lengths. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option could be:

```
test[t(sapply(rownames(test), grepl, colnames(test)))]
```

Answer (score 0):

We could add `table` attribute to the `matrix`, convert to long form with `as.data.frame`, use `subset` to subset the elements and convert to a named vector with `setNames`

```
with(subset(as.data.frame.table(test), sub("_\\d+", "", Var2) ==
         Var1, select = 2:3), setNames(Freq, Var2))
```

-output

```
#   aaa_1     aaa_2     aaa_3     bbb_1     bbb_2     bbb_3     ccc_1     ccc_2     ccc_3 
#1.6563422 3.1174159 3.5855340 0.3218447 0.5638403 2.7593073 0.1595813 0.2933381 0.4131952
```

NOTE: Values are different as there was no `set.seed`